# What's the difference between contract creation and contract deployment?

Tags: contract-development

According to the solidity documentation:

One way to create contracts programmatically on Ethereum is via the JavaScript API web3.js. It has a function called web3.eth.Contract to facilitate contract creation. When a contract is created, its constructor is executed once.

Now, How is this different from deploying a contract ? When we deploy a contract, the constructor is executed once. So what's the difference between contract creation and contract deployment ? Or, do they mean the same thing ?

Answer (score 1):

They mean the same thing.

I would claim *creation* is a bit more abstract term than *deployment*. When a user creates a contract it can be called creation or deployment (as he has to deploy the code into the blockchain). But when a contract creates another contract it can't be called deployment, only creation.